# How do you have a clickable header bring you down the same page you're on to a new section

Tags: html, css

For example I have a Contact Me clickable header and the information I want for people to see is at the bottom of my page. So I want it to directly scroll down when they click "Contact Me"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just plain HTML:

```html
<a href='#anchor'>Contact Me</a>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div id='anchor'>Contact info</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your contact me with anchor tag linking it to the div id like so: `<a href="#contact">Contact</a>` I included some live code below, as well. Hope this helps!

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a ex a dui bibendum rutrum sed vitae lorem. Cras lacinia eros vel facilisis faucibus. Donec molestie dolor vel congue fringilla. Vestibulum elit tellus, dapibus ut enim eu, gravida ultricies mi. Maecenas nec ornare nibh, vitae luctus risus. Aenean sit amet nisl convallis, lacinia nisi sed, convallis ligula. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eget mollis leo. Maecenas ultricies efficitur nisi sed cursus. Etiam nec malesuada est, vitae consectetur massa.

Suspendisse potenti. In sed lacinia neque, id tincidunt elit. Aenean a leo sit amet velit fringilla faucibus a id dolor. Integer nec vehicula ante, ut ultricies risus. Donec nibh purus, feugiat sed nisl vel, iaculis feugiat magna. Morbi neque augue, condimentum vitae sapien sed, rhoncus pulvinar diam. Praesent vestibulum libero purus, quis malesuada sapien convallis at. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Ut pharetra mi et pellentesque scelerisque. Mauris vel sapien sed augue rhoncus eleifend tristique ac metus. Proin ac vehicula metus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ac tortor vel metus accumsan semper a vitae dui. Sed in eleifend erat, id dictum mauris. Vestibulum ac diam id eros venenatis iaculis.

Suspendisse pharetra pellentesque leo eget hendrerit. Integer et urna posuere, egestas nisi sollicitudin, mattis neque. Nulla lacinia ut mauris et aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi in eros commodo, imperdiet urna a, interdum tortor. Donec sagittis, lacus sed tincidunt porttitor, tellus lectus consectetur tortor, eu malesuada urna enim at nulla. Etiam sed tellus ut ex accumsan maximus vitae sit amet ex.

Morbi et eleifend eros, in mattis nisi. Nunc molestie finibus porttitor. Aenean tincidunt, odio vitae feugiat interdum, nibh massa vestibulum nisl, a blandit tortor ante ut quam. Donec condimentum, lacus mattis condimentum feugiat, diam orci blandit justo, quis hendrerit ligula nisl vel urna. Nunc tincidunt orci vel eros vehicula dignissim. In egestas id lacus et dictum. Nulla eros massa, tempus porttitor libero et, posuere consequat quam. Fusce rutrum tincidunt velit, aliquam pharetra ipsum volutpat vitae. Duis ultricies ut metus a convallis. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Donec mattis sem sed massa rhoncus placerat. Pellentesque sollicitudin aliquet sapien in sollicitudin.

Suspendisse varius tempor accumsan. Sed in libero sed erat convallis ultrices. Vestibulum at congue arcu. Maecenas imperdiet ultricies dui, at faucibus lacus tempus et. Maecenas fringilla ultrices interdum. Nullam laoreet dignissim massa vitae dignissim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin semper arcu in dui pretium malesuada. Aenean euismod malesuada vestibulum. Donec mattis, sem at rhoncus egestas, quam arcu sagittis sapien, nec maximus ante quam eget mauris. Quisque eleifend non lorem et venenatis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Duis tincidunt nunc turpis, in ullamcorper leo imperdiet eget. In vulputate massa faucibus, efficitur enim luctus, tempor mauris. Suspendisse sed condimentum est, sed lobortis leo. Aenean rutrum nibh malesuada ligula mollis, ut vulputate diam vestibulum.

Donec dapibus neque in velit scelerisque, eget semper orci fringilla. Donec at diam quam. Fusce in enim diam. Vivamus id facilisis ligula. Curabitur sed auctor purus. Vestibulum id nibh et odio varius varius eu vel quam. Donec et malesuada libero. Quisque in velit felis. In sed ipsum elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi luctus ex quis sollicitudin dignissim. Aenean tincidunt tristique libero, vitae rhoncus elit eleifend eget. Sed venenatis gravida enim ac fringilla. In blandit nunc non sapien eleifend convallis. Donec a lacinia nisl, et consequat metus.

Donec facilisis, turpis id condimentum sollicitudin, magna justo varius est, auctor suscipit enim arcu at nibh. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris purus enim, euismod non ultrices at, egestas et magna. Donec laoreet feugiat elit ut porttitor. Pellentesque facilisis bibendum ornare. Cras diam lorem, maximus id nulla at, feugiat sollicitudin felis. Curabitur nisi erat, tincidunt sed semper a, porta non justo.

Duis non dictum purus. Vivamus lobortis enim ut urna ornare, eget pharetra ipsum pretium. Donec mauris nisi, porta non porttitor vehicula, vehicula non orci. Maecenas elementum venenatis interdum. Integer est metus, lobortis id rhoncus in, fringilla nec erat. Vestibulum aliquet mi sit amet odio ultricies mollis. Ut lobortis sapien ac feugiat facilisis. Morbi tellus metus, vulputate facilisis sem quis, gravida auctor dolor. Aliquam nec dictum eros. Suspendisse at laoreet sem. Vestibulum pharetra mauris sapien, id sagittis magna fermentum ac.

Cras congue pulvinar elementum. Phasellus volutpat nibh consequat, finibus nunc eget, laoreet ligula. Phasellus vel tincidunt ante. Maecenas egestas, risus a accumsan facilisis, mi sem ultricies massa, sit amet dignissim sem magna non leo. Vivamus urna libero, aliquet id tortor quis, lobortis laoreet ex. Pellentesque et ligula quis mauris venenatis rutrum. Nullam ultrices, ex vel porttitor congue, magna libero aliquam ipsum, rutrum tristique velit augue vitae augue. Fusce id risus sed odio volutpat posuere. Nam eget dictum urna, quis ullamcorper orci.

Donec imperdiet risus nunc, a fermentum tellus porttitor ut. Nulla laoreet orci ac mollis rutrum. Morbi ut libero ex. Vestibulum faucibus magna ultrices felis iaculis, vel interdum lorem mattis. Phasellus mauris leo, interdum ac ultricies et, pulvinar pretium eros. Morbi ac placerat sem. Maecenas suscipit molestie massa, at porta mauris aliquet sit amet. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi ullamcorper, velit vel ornare porta, felis lectus elementum massa, quis mattis lacus velit congue diam. Mauris ligula velit, auctor id nisi in, tempus ultricies nisl.
</p>


<div id="contact">
<h1>CONTACT US</h1>
</div>
```